# PartialFunction type inference in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference

Let's consider the following function:

```
def printPfType[T](pf:PartialFunction[T, _])(implicit m:Manifest[T]) = {
  println(m.toString)
}
```

Then I define the following test class:

```
case class Test(s:String, i:Int)
```

I can't write this:

```
printPfType {
  case Test(_,i) => i
}
```

because the compiler can't infer the first parametric type of the PartialFunction. I have to specify it explicitly:

```
printPfType[Test] {
  case Test(_,i) => i
}
```

But then the `Test` type appears twice. Is there a technique to avoid this? How can I help the type inferer to avoid the duplicate?

Answer (score 5):

See this [thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Type-inference-craps-out-td2134282.html). Type inference cannot handle this problem. Quote from the spec:

> An anonymous function can be defined
>   by a sequence of cases { case p1
>   => b1 . . . case pn => bn } which appear as an expression without a
>   prior match. **The expected type of such
>   an expression must in part be defined**.
>   It must be either scala.Functionk[S1,
>   . . . , Sk, R] for some k > 0, or
>   scala.PartialFunction[S1, R], where
>   the argument type(s) S1, . . . , Sk
>   must be fully determined, but the
>   result type R may be undetermined.